# Firebase ID token has expired. Get a fresh ID token from your client app and try again (auth/id-token-expired)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using postman to mimic requests to firebase and firestore, i am using `FBAuth` middleware for protected routes like uploading images, posting a comment, so i need to make sure that the user is authenticated before posting an image or writing a comment, but i always get a message in **postman** that my id token has expired,

**FBAuth middleware:**

```
const FBAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    let idToken;
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
        idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
    } else {
        console.error('no token found');
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'unauthorized' })
    }

    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then(decodedToken => {
        req.user = decodedToken;
        console.log(decodedToken);
        return db.collection('users').where('userId', '==', req.user.uid)
            .limit(1)
            .get();

    }).then(data => {
        req.user.handle = data.docs[0].data().handle;
        return next();
    })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(403).json(err)
        })
}
```

Then use the middleware like this:

```
app.post('/user/image', FBAuth, uploadImage);`
```

In post man, i am using the token i get from **sign in** process to make the request, but i always get that message:

```
{
    "code": "auth/id-token-expired",
    "message": "Firebase ID token has expired. Get a fresh ID token from your client app and try again (auth/id-token-expired). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token."
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that you have a problem on the frontend, not on the backend.  Your frontend has simply delivered an expired token.  It will need to keep refreshing the token every hour, since that's how long they last.

You haven't really said anything about your frontend at all, but it should be using an ID token listener to get fresh tokens delivered every hour.  If the client is JavaScript, it would use [onTokenIdChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged).  If you're copying the token from your web or mobile client for use in postman, know that you will need to keep generating and copying a new tokens during development in order to stay fresh every hour.

Comment: Thank you, i am using the token from sign in process to mimic uploading images using postman, this is not a time enough for token to expire

Comment: Well, the error message is clearly disagreeing about that.  It's saying the token you provided is expired.  If you think this is a bug, I'm sure the Firebase engineers would like your steps to reproduce this bug as a new issue on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I logged into my app and immediately grabbed the token and put it in postman and received the message that the token is expired.  I'm new to react/javascript.  I'm using Next.Js where would I put the onTokenIdChanged if I wanted to use it?  UseEffect?  Thanks